# Sympy holds function, instead of returning float

Tags: python, sympy

I am working on a school project, and got an error which I don't know how to solve. While using Sympy to get the partial derivatives of a function and later entering a x and y value, I am not able to get a single number out of it. I am holding a long expression like this:

```
-0.641831092731613*(0.5 + 0.2*pi)*exp(-0.2*(-pi - 2.5)**2) + 0.479462137331569*exp(-0.2*(-pi - 2.5)**2) - 0.96274663909742*(0.5 - 0.2*pi)*exp(-0.2*(-2.5 + pi)**2) + 0.719193205997354*exp(-0.2*(-2.5 + pi)**2)
```

I am using the N function build in Sympy, but it does not seem to do the trick. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

code:

```
def afgeleide(variabele):
    x, y = sympy.symbols('x y', real=True)
    z = -1*sympy.cos(x)*sympy.cos(y)*(sympy.exp(-0.1*((x-sympy.pi)**2+(y-sympy.pi)**2))+1.5*sympy.exp(-0.1*((x+sympy.pi)**2+(y+sympy.pi)**2)))
    if variabele == "x":
        return z.diff(x)
    elif variabele == "y":
        return z.diff(y)
    else:
        return "verkeerde variabele, probeer x of y"
def gradientdescent(beginx,beginy,alpha,aantalpogingen=0):
    x, y = sympy.symbols('x y',real = True)
    afgeleidex = afgeleide("x").subs([(x,beginx),(y,beginy)])
    sympy.N(afgeleidex)
    print(afgeleidex)
```

Comment: What is the output to the command `N(-0.641831092731613*(0.5 + 0.2*pi)*exp(-0.2*(-pi - 2.5)**2) + 0.479462137331569*exp(-0.2*(-pi - 2.5)**2) - 0.96274663909742*(0.5 - 0.2*pi)*exp(-0.2*(-2.5 + pi)**2) + 0.719193205997354*exp(-0.2*(-2.5 + pi)**2))`?

Comment: My guess is that `pi` is currently a symbolic variable instead of a numerical variable. In this case, you should use `subs` to replace the symbol with the number.

Comment: A problem might be that you declare x and y inside two functions. Variables can have the same name, but be different variables internally.  Can you [edit]() your post and add a reproducible example, including the `import`s and a call to your function with some specific values?

Comment: You do `sympy.N(afgeleidex)`and then `print(afgeleidex)`. Sympy doesn't work like that.   `sympy.N(afgeleidex)` calculates a numeric value (if possible), but doesn't change ` `afgeleidex`.  You need to assign the result to something, and then print that result.  Or directly call `print(sympy.N(afgeleidex))`. See also [sympy's gotchas](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#symbols).